# Rust htons and ntohs

Tags: rust

I have a program that has been relying on `native::io::net::{htons, ntohs}` but now errors on `Could not find 'io' in 'packet::native'`.  The change seems to have happened some time in the last week

Searching doesn't yield much info about the change and a search for `htons` or `ntohs` in the docs doesn't yield any useful information.

What is the (new?) standard way to perform `htons` or `ntohs` in Rust?

An obvious solution would be to write my own but one would expect that it would be in the standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are now in `std::sys_common::net`, but `std::sys_common` is private. But their implementation in `src/libstd/sys/common/net.rs` is very simple:

```
pub fn htons(u: u16) -> u16 {
    u.to_be()
}
pub fn ntohs(u: u16) -> u16 {
    Int::from_be(u)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `from_be` and `to_be` functions on the `Int` trait.  Network order is big endian, so this is equivalent.

You can find example usages in the documentation for them:

http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/num/trait.Int.html#method.to_be

http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/num/trait.Int.html#method.from_be

Comment: Thanks. I've found this is how it works under the hood for [libstd](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f09279395b6ca40f1398277971586197f949738a/src/libstd/sys/common/net.rs)